# Deploying Sinatra app on Heroku

Tags: configuration, sinatra, rackup

I am perplexed by something that isn't actually a practical problem - just a conceptual conundrum - about deploying a Sinatra app on Heroku.

I have two apps, identical in just about every respect, except that one puts most of its logic in a file that does not contain the Sinatra::Base class and uses a 'require otherfilename' to pick up the logic it needs. That Sinatra:Base class is named Kincalc.

For the app with all the logic in one file (that is, the same file that contains the Sinatra:Base class), in my config.ru file, the last line reads "run Sinatra::Application" and it launches fine. But in the other app, if I include that as the last line, the app uploads properly and says it was "deployed to Heroku" but it brings up a "Not found" message. When I have the last line read 'run Kincalc', it loads fine.

I have checked this back and forth and there is nothing different about how these two apps are built, except for the fact that one uses a second file for the logic (which is also at root). Why should this be a problem, or is this really the problem? When I try to put the second file (the one without the Sinatra class) in a separate lib folder, it still works when I call the class name but not when I call "Sinatra::Application."

Comment: please show the heroku error message as well as your config.ru files and the 'app files' or accept @KonstantinHaase's answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code at top level will be delegated to `Sinatra::Application`, so this would be a scenario for running a classic application:

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'hi'
end

# config.ru
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

If you define a modular app, you would run it like this:

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra/base'

class Kincalc < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    'hi'
  end
end

# config.ru
require './app'
run Kincalc
```

Now I assume what you are trying to do is this:

```
# otherfilename.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'hi'
end

# app.rb
require 'sinatra/base'

class Kincalc < Sinatra::Base
  require './otherfilename'
end

# config.ru
require './app'
run Kincalc # Sinatra::Application seems to work
```

The behavior you experience (getting a 404 File Not Found) is actually correct, as `require` does not care about the lexical scope it is called in. Check out the following example

```
# a.rb
puts "in a, top level: #{self.inspect}"

module Example
  puts "in a, nested: #{self.inspect}"
  require 'b'
end

# b.rb
puts "in b: #{self.inspect}"
```

The resulting output should be:

```
in a, top level: main
in a, nested: Example
in b: main
```

So, if you want to use *one* modular application, you should do something like this:

```
# otherfilename.rb
Kincalc.get '/' do
  'hi'
end
```

Or open the class again:

```
# otherfilename.rb
class Kincalc
  get '/' do
    'hi'
  end
end
```

Or you could actually have `otherfilename.rb` make it's definitions on `Sinatra::Application` and utilize that in `Kincalc`.

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra/base'
require './otherfilename'

class Kincalc < Sinatra::Base
  use Sinatra::Application
end
```

Or you could change where top level DSL methods are delegated to:

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra/base'

class Kincalc < Sinatra::Base
  Sinatra::Delegator.target = self
  require './otherfilename'
end
```

Comment: In my situation, the routes are in the Sinatra::Base class, Kincalc, which is in kincalc.rb. That file also has 'require 'sinatra'' and 'require './otherfilename' statements above the class def. The logic for the URIs (post '/calculate' do, etc) are all in otherfilename.rb. So how would I map your last suggestion to this structure? Assuming I want to keep the routes in the Kincalc class (below the require statement), what does config.ru then look like? When I tried changing that from 'run Kincalc' to run Sinatra::Application, it still didn't work.

Comment: No I didn't get that quite right. the routes are all in the Sinatra::Base class (in kincalc.rb) but the logic for them is in the otherfilename.rb (placeholder). I want to keep the top level app file clean, just having the routes, and the functions and logic used in the routes separate. I guess I don't get how lexical scope affects this.

Comment: But again, it's really a hypothetical problem anyway. I guess I could just use 'run Kincalc' and let it go - it's really no different either way!